# Rails: What gives date/datetime the (1i), (2i), etc values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't seem to find how a date or datetime gets to have (1i), (2i), etc. What method gives this? I'm asking because I have a gem that breaks this functionality in Rails, and I want to make a test for it, and fix it.

This is the new error that happens when I install the gem:

```
undefined method `published_at(1i)=' for #<Page:0xc25ccd4> (NoMethodError)
./app/controllers/admin/pages_controller.rb:21:in `update'
./vendor/plugins/exception_notification/lib/exception_notifier.rb:19:in `call'
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:29
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:14:in `with_scope'
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:28:in `/^(?:|I )press "([^"]*)"(?: within "([^"]*)")?$/'
features/domain_linking.feature:11:in `And I press "Update page"'
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to take a look into the Rails source code, starting from `ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper` module and digging further in to get to the appropriate function.

Comment: Yes, I've done this but have gotten no where. Besides, that's for the part of the view already. In my error, it's in the side of ActiveRecord that's broken. `undefined method 'published_at(1i)=' for #<Page:0xc25ccd4> (NoMethodError)`. That means there's no setter method because the gem I have somehow broke it. But I don't think this setter method is automatically available. When I do `@page.published_at(1i)= somevalue` I get an `syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'`. So it seems to be available only sometimes. Which confuses me.

Comment: My gut says that it's the request parser that's somehow broken, since it's meant to form the (1i), (2i) etc into a single Date / DateTime object.

Comment: Hmm.. the gem doesn't change anything in the controllers or the views. Thanks, I'll investigate further.

Comment: Looking further into it, it seems that the code should be just above Rack, somewhere in the Rails side of things. From looking at the Rack code, that handles the array case, parsing `[]` into `Array`'s.

Comment: I couldn't find the problem, so I just disabled overriding the ActiveRecord's methods first, and defined my own. Thanks for your help Daemin.